# sudo: apt-get: command not found

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, gnome-terminal

When I run `apt-get update` as `root` user it's working well, but not working for `apt-get install build-essential manpages-dev` (showing `apt-get command not found`).

Comment: What does `which apt-get` say ran as `root`?

Comment: What do you mean by running as root? using sudo or not?

Comment: result of which apt-get
/usr/bin/apt-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As normal user run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, 
`apt-get` is working for root user.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try simulating the command without doing anything else, in order to get only the command's error messages:

```
sudo apt update  
apt install --simulate build-essential manpages-dev
```

If there are no error messages, try running the commands as root without the `--simulate` option.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install build-essential manpages-dev
```

Comment: OP said `apt-get install build-essential manpages-dev` doesn't work. why do you think it will work with `--simulate` switch?

Comment: In case he ran`apt–get install` (with an en dash between apt and get) or apt~get install, either of which would result in something like an `apt~get command not found` error message, I'm trying to trick him with the sneaky placebo `--simulate` option into copy/pasting the correct command instead.

Comment: In this case, I would ask him if he typed the command correctly. You didn't mentioned in your answer explicitly saying to copy/paste this.

Comment: Either way, the cat's out of the bag now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PATH variable (echo $PATH) to see if there's something wrong there (please post the output here).

Also, try to copy a clean .bashrc file from /etc/skel (backup your current ~/.bashrc file before)

Hope this helps ;D

Answer (score -1):

You first login as root user, then try this one,

```
apt-get update;

apt-cache search package name;
```

It will show the proper package name,
Then you can install it through the `apt-get install package name`.
[https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=291651](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=291651][1])

Comment: Its working after install all the packages.
Thanks Man.